# Removing entire user account footprint on uninstall Wix

Tags: c#, wix

When I did MSI install (Wix), we create a virtual user account which visible under `User` plus a `user` is also created within `C:\Users`.

[image]

Now on un-install of MSI, I would like to remove all the virtual user account also to be removed, how to achieve this ?

One way I'm aware to remove the folder, but what about removing user ?

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="$(var.PlatformProgramFilesFolder)">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="XYZ">
    </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `RemoveOnUninstall` to `yes` in the `UserElement`. Look at this [reference](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/user.html).

Comment: Thanks, could you please send me sample XML?